# How to unlist an arbitrary level in R nested list?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a nested list that has three levels. I need to unlist the middle level, but I have not found an easy way to do it.

E.g.

```
df1 <- data.frame(X = sample(100),
                  Y = sample(100))
df2 <- data.frame(X = sample(50),
                  Y = sample(50))
df3 <- data.frame(X = sample(150),
                  Y = sample(150),
                  Z = sample(150)) 
df4 <- data.frame(X = sample(20),
                  Y = sample(20),
                  Z = sample(20))

list1 <- list(A = df1, B = df2)
list2 <- list(A = df3, B = df4)

masterList <- list(list1, list2)
```

What I want to achieve is

```
newMasterList <- list(A = rbind(df1,df2), B = rbind(df3,df4))
```

I've tried unlist() with the both recursive options but they don't yield the desired result:

```
newMasterListFAIL1 <- lapply(seq_along(masterList), function(x) unlist(masterList[[x]], recursive = F))

newMasterListFAIL2 <- lapply(seq_along(masterList), function(x) unlist(masterList[[x]]))
```

Comment: Try `lapply(masterList, function(x) do.call(rbind, x))`

Comment: quicker ;) slower approach: `lapply(masterList, function(x) Reduce(rbind, x))` or using `rbindlist` from `data.table` package works: `lapply(masterList, rbindlist)`

Comment: Thank you both! Answered my question. I need to get more acquainted with data.table. It seems like a great package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try fast `rbindlist` from `data.table` package (but your list of `data.frame` will be converted to a list of `data.table`):

```
library(data.table)

newMasterList = lapply(masterList, rbindlist)
```

The base R solution from @akrun:

```
newMasterList = lapply(masterList, function(x) do.call(rbind, x))
```

And an elegant solution from @David Arenburg

```
library(tidyr)

newMasterList = lapply(masterList, unnest)
```

Comment: I would also add `lapply(masterList, unnest)` if you don't want someone to steal your fame here. Also, probably should add @akrun comment as base alternative as you both came up with it yourself, and seems like arkun isn't going to post it.